# Check which viewController is running in IPhone application Programmatically in Appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is their any Possibilty to Check which viewController is running  in IPhone application Programmatically in Appdelegate

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? Are you looking for the top most visible view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this. You need to walk the view controller hierarchy starting with the main window's root view controller. If you encounter a `UINavigationController` you need to look at the `topViewController`. Once you get to a `UIViewController`, you need to look at the `modalViewController`, if any. If you have any tab bar controllers then you need to look at the currently selected tab.

Things like `UISplitViewController` complicates things since this can show two view controllers at once.

Here is the start of a category method you could add to `UIViewController`. This only handles regular view controllers and navigation controllers.

```
- (UIViewController *)topMostController {
    if (self.modalViewController) {
        return [self.modalViewController topMostController];
    } else {
        if ([self isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)self;

            return [nc.topViewController topMostController];
        } else {
            return self;
        }
    }
}
```

Call this from your app delegate on the key window's `rootViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've set the rootViewController property in your `AppDelegate`:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 1):

For view controller it is not possible to get the curent running viewcontroller name.

for that you write one following method in your app delegate file & then call getCurentViewController method in each viewcontroller view did load or view did appear if you are not allocating agin by passing self to it

```
-(void) getCurentViewController:(UIViewController*) vc
{
      if([vc isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"vcName")])
      {
          //write your code here
      }
      else if([vc isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"vcName1")])
      {  
         //write your code here
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *currentViewController = yourRootViewController;
while (currentViewController.presentedViewController) {
    currentViewController = currentViewController.presentedViewController;
}
//currentViewController is now your top-most viewController
//I use this same snippet in my production code
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it doesn't work as I hoped. When this gets to a `UINavigationController`, it doesn't return the top view controller in the navigation stack.

Comment: You may be right about that, I use this just so I can present a modal viewcontroller from the top view controller. In that case it wouldn't matter whether I was at the top viewcontroller in the navigation stack. I wasn't sure if that's what the question was requiring.